# Redirecting after AJAX post in Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, redirect, django-generic-views

I use Django's built-in DeleteView and I've assigned a value to the `success_url` attribute. Now in my template, I trigger this view via JQuery' $.post() method. When the item is deleted, I don't get redirected to the `success_url`. After some search, I found that it seems to be a problem of AJAX post method, which ignores the redirection.

I fixed it by adding a function to set the `window.location="#myRedirectionURL"` as the third parameter of `$.post()` in JQuery.

However, this way seems not very Django. Essentially, it solves the problem from the aspect of AJAX, instead of Django. What's more, it leaves the `success_url` in DeleteView useless( But you still have to assign a value to `success_url`, or Django will raise an error).

So is it the right way to get redirected when you post via AJAX? Is there any better way to do it?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I would execute the `location.href='#myRedirectionURL'` js code inside the success_url template, with a `setTimeout` delay while showing a nice message like 'the deletion was ok'

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ajax will not redirect pages!

What you get from a redirect is the html code from the new page inside the data object on the POST response.

If you know where to redirect the user if whatever action fails, you can simply do something like this:

On the server,

In case you have an error

```
response = {'status': 0, 'message': _("Your error")}
```

If everything went ok

```
response = {'status': 1, 'message': _("Ok")} # for ok
```

Send the response:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json')
```

on the html page:

```
$.post( "{% url 'your_url' %}", 
         { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token}}' , 
           other_params: JSON.stringify(whatever)
         },  
         function(data) {
             if(data.status == 1){ // meaning that everyhting went ok
                // do something
             }
             else{
                alert(data.message)
                // do your redirect
                window.location('your_url')
             }
        });
```

If you don't know where to send the user, and you prefer to get that url from the server, just send that as a parameter:

```
response = {'status': 0, 'message': _("Your error"), 'url':'your_url'}
```

then substitute that on window location:

```
 alert(data.message)
 // do your redirect
 window.location = data.url;
```

Comment: you've made it very clear for me. Thank you very much. So redirecting  via AJAX codes (with a url parameter in JSON response from Django view, if necessary) is the only to solve this problem, right? Then I won't feel uncomfortable with it.

Comment: How can I pass POST data to my view . With window.location='url' I can only call a url but I cannot send custom data that should be shown in the url

Comment: Now (Django 1.7>=) we can even use the JsonResponse to further simplify the response line, great answer though.

Answer (score 5):

<del>http://hunterford.me/how-to-handle-http-redirects-with--jquery-and-django/</del>

**Edit: source unavailable**

this one works for me, perhaps looks like hack

django middleware

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class AjaxRedirect(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if request.is_ajax():
            if type(response) == HttpResponseRedirect:
                response.status_code = 278
        return response
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
        if (xhr.status == 278) {
            window.location.href = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The link is no longer working. Here is more information on how I get this work: 1. in settings.py, I added `AjaxRedirect` under `MIDDLEWARE`.  2. change inherited class from `object` to `MiddlewareMixin`.

Comment: request.is_ajax() has been deprec in 3.1

Answer (score 0):

django-ajax's ajaxPost allows for redirects if you pass a normal redirect(URL) to it (as a json response). Jquery ajax() methods did not work in my case.