# how Django view get the post data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I have a question about update HTML when I use view.py.  This is my part of HTML, I have many buttons, and when I click one of the buttons, it will pass just the corresponds data to view.

```
$.ajax({
        url:"/file_parse/",
        type:"POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:JSON.stringify({
            'data':dataname
        })
```

You can see I post some data ,and get the Post data in my view's function, finally I save the result to my model(database). When I click one button, and my view's function will do something,so I get a different result every time when I click a different button.This is the first view, dopase is a function to save data and it is doing right:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def file_parse(request):
    uploadfile_info = upload_document.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        info_name = request.data.get('data')
        doparse(info_name)
        file_name = re.findall(r'[^/]+(?!.*\/)', str(info_name))
        data_list = ES_device.objects.filter(device_name = file_name)
        # data_list = ES_device.objects.values('device_name', 'device_type').distinct()
        context = {'data_list': data_list}
        # return Response(context, None, 'logfile/data_bi.html')
        return render(request, 'logfile/data_bi.html', context)
        # return render_to_response('logfile/data_bi.html', locals())
    else:
        context = {'uploadfile_info': uploadfile_info}
        return render(request, 'logfile/file_parse.html', context)`
```

This is url

```
url(r'^file_parse/$', file_parse),
url(r'^data_bi/$', data_to_list),
```

This is the view I want to show the result:

```
def data_to_list(request):
    data_list = ES_device.objects.all()
    context = {'data_list': data_list}
    #return render(request, 'logfile/data_bi.html', context)
    return render_to_response('logfile/data_bi.html', locals())
```

But when I click one button, the first view successfully execute，and the data is saved to model, but it can not open another html(data_bi.html),I know something is wrong,but couldn't find it. Please give me some advice and show me how to achieve this.THANKS a lot.

Comment: if you want to redirect by ajax, you need parse data and redirect by js.

Comment: Please look into  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137910/redirecting-after-ajax-post-in-django

Comment: ajax: window.location can redirect to the new page,but how to achieve: update data when i clicked another button ?