# Redirect After Ajax call using Django if query's match

Tags: python, ajax, django

I grasp that this code isn't working because the request is somehow insufficient, but I'm uncertain as to how to go about correcting it. I'm trying to configure it so that, if the ajax data matches the username, it will redirect to home.html. Any help would be so greatly cherished! (PS: the print calls are working - if the user exists, it prints the "else" statement and vice versa. Nevertheless, the redirect still doesn't work!)

views.py

```
 def profile(request):
        profname = request.GET.get('profname', None)
        obj = User.objects.filter(username=profname)
        if not obj:
            print("I need this time to redirect to error page")

        else:
            print ("I need this to redirect home")
            return redirect('home')
        return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<h1>jkkk</h1>
     <a id="butt" href="#">Get Data</a>
 </body>
 <script>


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#butt").click(function(){

           $.ajax({
           type: "get",
           url: 'profile',
           datatype:'json',
            data: {
            'profname': 'jillsmith',
            },

       }); 
  });
});
</script>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.explore, name='explore'),
     path('happening/profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
     path('happening/', views.happening, name='happening'),
     path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
     path('happening/test/', views.test, name='test'),
     path('home/likes/', views.likes, name='likes'),



]
```

Comment: You're not going to get a redirect in the front-end by returning a redirect response from the Ajax request. That's simply not how Ajax works. Also you're not doing anything with the response, whatever it is, since you have no `success` callback.

Comment: How would I go about rectifying this?

Comment: Since it appears you want a redirect in both cases, I don't see how Ajax is the right tool.  It looks like you can achieve the desired effect without any Javascript, just make your button into a link to the url you're using now, that will then check the database and do the appropriate server side redirect

Comment: Yes, but in the final project I am going to send the text of the button to the back end, seeing if the user exists, and then redirect to a page with that user's particular info.

Comment: Then you either need a parameter in the URL, or to send the data in a form

Comment: Or try one of the solutions in the question @TheodoreHowell links to in his edit. Looks like your question is actually a duplicate of that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting after AJAX post in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137910/redirecting-after-ajax-post-in-django)

Comment: I can redirect via window.location in javascript, but how would I go about passing the info  --- in this case, 'jillsmith' -- to the page I redirect to?

Comment: The same way you always pass information to a view in Django - with parameters in the URL.

Comment: Jeez, I get that. How do I do it using the solution you just recommended ---         $.ajax({
           type: "get",
           url: 'profile',
           datatype:'json',
      data: {
            'profname': 'jilsmith',
            },
     success: function(data) {
                if(data.status == 0){ 
    alert("error page");
    window.location = data.url
             }

Comment: I didn't actually recommend a particular solution - I wouldn't do that because I'm still unaware of exactly what you're trying to do. But if you're doing it that way, you can just put the logic in the backend to ensure the `data.url` is correct.

Comment: the link I am clicking has the word 'jillsmith' in it. I want to send 'jillsmith' to back end, check if 'jillsmith' is a user, and then redirect to a page with her info if she is in fact a user. I've done this using the answer you provided, window.location via javascript. However, in this case I don't know how to call the link with a parameter.

Comment: I didn't provide an answer, I just linked to a previous question that was very similar, whose existence I was only alerted to by another poster. I think there are a few different solutions suggested there, this is only one (and my preference would be to just use a link and do it all via the backend, as I did suggest earlier). Anyway, I'm not sure how familiar you are with Django but see here for how to use URL parameters: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put a return statement in front of your call to redirect, it returns an HttpResponse Object and that needs returned to the caller.

EDIT: OP updated and added return, however this should be a good fix. Please try to pass URL and Boolean indicating whether you should redirect or not. [Django AJAX Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137910/redirecting-after-ajax-post-in-django)

Comment: And if you are using a app_name in url conf dont forget to use 'app_name:home'

Comment: That was a typo in the code I posted. The issue is that it still doesn't redirect, yet it prints.

Comment: Can you try to use reverse_lazy()?  use this from django.urls import reverse_lazy

Comment: and just replace that for redirect, I cannot see all of your code and sometimes this can be an issue depending on where your statements are placed

Comment: After re-reading it, you also might want to take care of the redirect from the JS, pass data with the url to redirect to and a boolean indicating if you should redirect, and use JS to redirect once that AJAX returns. I think that might be the real issue

Comment: No. I get this error.     response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 93, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: '__proxy__' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Hey man, one more question if you don't mind ... How would I go about sending the 'profname' variable to the page I redirect to? I need this info to pull from the backend files in regards to what will load on the page.

Comment: @Jay if you are using Django >= 1.2 please look into django messages. You can pass context via the backend to redirected pages just like you are trying to do. Its in the docs and super easy to use. If you need helping finding more let me know!

Comment: I am trying to pass from the frontend to redirected pages, not the backend.

Comment: If you are wanting to take data from that ajax response, that you are using to redirect, you can pass the data in the redirect call as a POST method to that page, or you can use messages to do the same thing. Messages will do what you need and bring the data from frontend, to backend, to frontend.